# I want to store metric units in a database - what datatype should I use?

Tags: mysql, database-design, postgresql

I'd like to store height which would eventually be displayed in Imperial/US ( 6 ft 4 for example ) in a database which is currently MySQL ( which I plan to migrate to PostgreSQL ).

I'm wondering what unit is good for this type of storage, and what column type I should use? I'm thinking centimeters/metric system and some numeric column type, but would be great if someone can provide insight.

Comment: Only three countries use imperial measurement, so metric would have my vote.

Comment: @OMG although the metric market for American football pitches is rather limited.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: Conversion is just a presentation issue

Comment: @OMG in which case it is irrelevant how many countries use imperial - even if every country did.

Answer (score 1):

I think it mostly depends on what operations are to take place on the data. If it is just going to be stored and retrieved for display, then store it as text. If you need to do calculations like average and range, store it in a numerical type after reducing to a base unit of measure (e.g., inches, or hundredths of an inch). The choice of integer or floating-point type again depends on what calculations you need to perform.

The only reason to convert to metric in the db and then back to Imperial units for output would be if you need metric for some other reason, and one that is more important/frequent than generating output in Imperial. Otherwise all you are doing is introducing rounding errors in both directions.

Comment: -1 for suggesting storing as text - even if it is just going to be outputted as text and no calculations will ever be performed, a number type is better because `text` is going to introduce consistency issues (One record says 6'4" one says 6ft4in - yuck). +1 for excellent reasoning on pointless conversions.

Comment: Agreed with above with experience with the same example scenario.  Data format is completely inconsistant and causes many issues both in applications and when it's time to run reports.

Comment: @user533832 storing the number as text if you are not performing any calculations, is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

store it as centimetres using an int datatype.  Note 1cm = 0.39370078740157477in

Comment: or more conveniently 1 inch is by defn 25.4mm

Comment: Actually, the way to express this is that 2.54 cm = 1 in **exactly**. (Reference [here](http://ts.nist.gov/WeightsAndMeasures/Metric/metrsty3.cfm).) (Like @Martin wrote while I was writing this. :))

Answer (score 1):

If they are continous quantities then store them in metres as a float and convert into metres, metres+cm, feet, furlongs in the report.

If they are fixed units that you don't want a rounding error on, like product sizes, then store them as an int in the smallest metric subdivison ml,mm,mg etc. and again convert on output

Comment: To minimize rounding errors, avoid conversions where possible.

Comment: I'm storing hundreds/thousands of peoples' heights.

Comment: That's why it's different storing continous quantities like someone's height. It's perfectly correct to have a rounding error on height since it already has a measurment accuracy. For a fixed number like the size of a coke can then it's 330ml or 10fl oz irrespective of it's actual content

Comment: @meder - that's not a particularly large amount of data for a modern rdbms. I don't see what bearing the quantity of data has on your original question.

Comment: If you are storing a person's height then there is an upper boundary (2.5m?) and you are unlikely to be measuring to more than 1mm - and probably more like 1cm, so just use an int of mm (or an unsigned char of cm if you really want to save space!)

Comment: Float is unreliable "Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: @Martin - just because data already has uncertainty is not a good reason to be lax about adding additional uncertainty through rounding errors. It's not perfectly correct at all.

Comment: @OMG attempting to compare exactly two physical properties like height may lead to problems with Dr Heisenburg.

Comment: @Ted - if you measure a person as 172cm, you only know they are between 171.5 and 172.5cm, any statement of their height more accurate than that is meaningless. It is rather more sensible to store that as a float with a finite binary representation that means it will return 1.7200000000001 that to store it as (int)172 implying that it is a fixed number. That's why floats are called REAL in Fortran.

Comment: @Martin - Actually, "172cm" doesn't tell you anything about the uncertainty of the measurement. You are confusing resolution with uncertainty, which is a common error. What if the uncertainty of each measurement is +/- 2cm? What's the experimenter supposed to do? Round to the nearest 4? No! The experimenter is supposed to record the measured number (ideally along with the uncertainty) without introducing even more error.

Comment: @Ted I doubt meder knows or cares precisely what the uncertainty in her measurements is - this is a common sense issue, isn't it. `int` sounds best to me too.

Comment: @JackPDouglas - I agree that uncertainty is probably irrelevant here. Fifteen years of working for a national standards lab probably left me a little oversensitive to these issues. Sloppy data handling and calculation methods have an incredible cost. These errors are often justified by the faulty reasoning that they don't matter because they are smaller than the errors already in the data. (That's what I understood Martin to be saying in his first comment to this post.) Every source of uncertainty _increases_ the overall uncertainty; it doesn't get "washed out in the noise."

Comment: @OMG Ponies: You quoted "Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems." Floating point values are stored as exact values. (Think through the implications of what an inexact value might be.) The problem in comparison is that the exact value that's stored is always the *closest FP approximation* to the value a programmer expects. But that's still an exact value. Repeat the same calculation, you'll get the same value. Store the result again, and the db will store the same approximation every time.

Answer (score 0):

Off of the top of my head I can't see why any database would be better than any other for storing metric units verses imperial ones. When approaching the problem of storing measurements, I see two major schools of thought. Store in the smallest reasonable units and use it as a base for everything (i.e. everything is in grams and cm). Another way would be to store the units with a scale if you're using mixed units, but this would probably complicate the setup more than necessary.

You can use an int or long to store the value if there is no possibility for measurements with a higher resolution than your base unit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only ever going to display in Imperial, then there may well be no good reason to store in metric. You will save yourself hassle by simply use an `int` to store the number of inches. If you need more resolution than that, either:

- uses an `int` to store (for example) tenths of an inch
- use numeric to store fractional values

As you are storing only "hundreds/thousands of peoples' heights", storage issues are very unlikely to be a worry.

Answer (score -2):

That might sounds awkward, but it may work for you in case Imperial measures are default.
Than I'd store length in CHAR(2) as HEX value. 6 ft 11 in becomes 6B, the column is sortable and you have no rounding problems which may happen in case you're storing metric lengths.

Comment: -1 very clever, but surely not I'm not the only one who would call this 'a bad idea'

Comment: Ok, not a good idea for metric units, but for feet and inches, can you think of anything better? :)

Comment: I can't think of anything worse. Height is a number, let's store it as a number! May suggestion is to store in inches and convert to a readable format in the presentation layer.